# Random number game refresh Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I have a "guess a random number" game, where my code generates a random number between 1 and 100, and you try and guess the number. I'd like to have a reset button that refreshes the game by changing the variable with the random number in it. This is the relevant code I have.

```
var comparedNumber = RandomNumber();

function RandomNumber(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
return randomNumber;    
}; 

refresh.onclick = function(){
genComparedNumber();
};
```

Function *Random Number* runs on page load, but I can't seem to get *comparedNumber* to change.

Comment: just do comparedNumber = RandomNumber(); on click

Answer (score 0):

Same logic as @juvian's answer

```js
var Game = {
 comparedNumber : randomNumber(),
 refreshNumber : function(){
  this.comparedNumber = randomNumber();
        alert(this.comparedNumber);
 },
 refreshButton : document.querySelector("#refresh-button")
}

function randomNumber(){
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
 return randomNumber;     
}

Game.refreshButton.addEventListener("click",Game.refreshNumber,false);
```

```html
<button id="refresh-button">Refresh</button>
```